# Cannot install ntp server

Tags: ntp

I install ntp server on ubuntu
Code:

```
aptitude update
aptitude -y upgrade
aptitude install ntp
```

Get error

```
ntp: depend libopts25 (>= 1:5.18) which is a virtual package
```

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried this `sudo apt-get install libopts25`

Comment: Hi Ravan. get error libopts25 is not available. I try install on another VM. But same above error

Answer (score 1):

Just add **libopts25** along with **ntp** like this `sudo apt-get install ntp libopts25`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ntp : Depends: libopts25 (>= 1:5.18.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

$ sudo apt-get install ntp libopts25
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
 ntp-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libopts25 ntp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 576 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,792 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libopts25 amd64 1:5.18.7-3 [57.8 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ntp amd64 1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.6 [518 kB]
Fetched 576 kB in 0s (615 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libopts25:amd64.
(Reading database ... 207420 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libopts25_1%3a5.18.7-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopts25:amd64 (1:5.18.7-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ntp.
Preparing to unpack .../ntp_1%3a4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ntp (1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libopts25:amd64 (1:5.18.7-3) ...
Setting up ntp (1:4.2.8p4+dfsg-3ubuntu5.6) ...
```

Comment: apt-get install ntp libopts25
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libopts25 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libopts25' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

You can install ntp server using following commands:

If you are using ubuntu server use `sudo apt-get install ntp`.

If you are using centos or RHEL then use `sudo yum install ntp`.

If this does not work try updating the source list repo.

Comment: Askubuntu is about Ubuntu related questions and answer, so answers to other Linux distributions are doesn't required.

Comment: just in case, he wanted to know