# Ubuntu 16.04 NTP server cannot read the key file

Tags: 16.04, ntp

I've read this [forum guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=862620) and a number of [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675441/cannot-install-ntp-server) to do with NTP servers.

I need to use authentication, but when I restart the ntp service I get an error in the log saying "ntpd[1710]: authreadkeys: file /etc/ntp.keys: Permission denied"

This is my config file:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 0.uk.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.uk.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.uk.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.uk.pool.ntp.org iburst

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

#enable auth
keys /etc/ntp.keys

trustedkey 17
controlkey 17
requestkey 17
```

I've confirmed that the file is readable, and have tried it in a number of permissions (400, 600, 700, 777).

How can I get my server to read the authentication keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing this same problem on 19.10.  It exhibits successive entries in `/var/log/syslog` like this...

```
Jun 10 12:34:56 HOSTNAME ntpd[12345]: authreadkeys: file '/etc/ntp.keys': Permission denied
Jun 10 12:34:56 HOSTNAME kernel: [...] audit: type=1400 audit(...): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/ntpkey_MD5key_HOSTNAME.1234567890" pid=12345 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Looking at what files in `/etc` AppArmor allows `ntpd` to access...

```
$ grep /etc/ntp /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd
  /etc/ntp.conf r,
  /etc/ntp.conf.dhcp r,
  /etc/ntpd.conf r,
  /etc/ntpd.conf.tmp r,
  /etc/ntp.keys r,
  /etc/ntp/** r,
  /etc/ntp.drift rwl,
  /etc/ntp.drift.TEMP rwl,
  /etc/ntp/drift* rwl,
```

...I could see that `/etc/ntp.keys` and `/etc/ntp/**` are included.  However, when using `ntp-keygen` to generate symmetric keys it creates `ntp.keys` as a symlink to a [filename including the host name and filestamp](http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/keygen.html#fmt)...

```
$ ls -l /etc/ntp*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 123 Jun 10 12:34 /etc/ntp.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root root 456 Jun 10 12:34 /etc/ntpkey_MD5key_HOSTNAME.1234567890
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  33 Jun 10 12:34 /etc/ntp.keys -> ntpkey_MD5key_HOSTNAME.1234567890
```

AppArmor evidently [doesn't follow symlinks](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/1485055) in its rules, so you either need to...

- Make `ntp.keys` a hard/only link instead of a symlink, or...
- Move the key file somewhere inside of a `/etc/ntp/` directory, or...
- The approach I took was inspired by [a comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/829410/ntp-server-permission-denied-when-trying-to-read-key-file#comment1058940_829454) on a duplicate post of this question.  I created a `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.ntpd` file with this content...

  ```
  /etc/ntpkey_MD5key_HOSTNAME.1234567890 r,
  ```

  ...then instructed AppArmor to [reload the profile](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor#loadrules) for `ntpd`...

  ```
  sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd
  ```

  ...and after restarting `ntpd`...

  ```
  sudo service ntp restart
  ```

  ...it successfully loaded the key file.

Answer (score 0):

I spun up an Ubuntu 14.04 instance and noticed that an app armor message in the logs after the same "permission denied" message.

Disabling the ntp profile for apparmor resolved the issue.